# How do I return a value that's dependent on another value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of products, and a table of rates. Each product has a set of different rates, and each set has a headline rate. How do I return the headline rate for each product?

Here's an example of the tables

Products pp

```
Id          Product
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
P1          Product1
P2          Product2
P3          Product3
```

Rates rr

```
Id       Productid        Headlinetier     Tier1    Tier2     Tier3
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
1        P1               3                0.1       0.2         0.3
2        P2               1                0.4       0.5         0.6
3        P3               2                0.7       0.8         0.9
```

How do I get the following results?

```
pp.Product                rr.Headlinerate
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
P1                        0.3
P2                        0.4
P3                        0.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to join the tables and a CASE statement to choose between the 3 tiers:

```
select
  p.product,
  case r.headlinetier
    when 1 then r.tier1
    when 2 then r.tier2
    when 3 then r.tier3
  end headlinerate
from products p inner join rates r
on r.productid = p.id
```

If your version is SQL Server 2012+ you can use [`choose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select
  p.product,
  choose(r.headlinetier, r.tier1, r.tier2, r.tier3) headlinerate
from products p inner join rates r
on r.productid = p.id
```